# Infer Schema Fails in Databricks Notebook

Tags: python, databricks, spark-streaming, azure-databricks, spark-structured-streaming

I have written a spark structured stream in Databricks. The first bit of code is to check if a delta table exists for my entity. If it does not then the delta table is created. Here, I wanted to use the infer schema option to get the schema for the delta table.

```py
# Check if the Delta table exists, if not create it
if not DeltaTable.isDeltaTable(spark, sink_path):
  # Read the Parquet data and infer the schema
  parquet_data = spark.read.option("inferSchema", "true").parquet(source_path)

# Create a Delta table with the inferred schema  
#### does not create transaction log

parquet_data.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save(sink_path)
print('delta table created')
```

I am getting this error. The source file has around 50 records. Why is the schema inference not working?

batch stream failed for advertiser: An error occurred while calling o671.load.
: com.databricks.sql.cloudfiles.errors.CloudFilesException: Cannot infer schema when the input path `dbfs:/mnt/raw/Entity1/fileA.parquet` is empty. Please try to start the stream when there are files in the input path, or specify the schema.

Comment: It seems the error related to your streaming query. Provide your streaming query.

Comment: Do you have any data in `dbfs:/mnt/raw/Entity1/fileA.parquet` ?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried your delta creation code, it's working fine,
The error is related to your streaming query.

I believe you streaming query is something similar to below code.

```
d1f = (
spark.readStream
    .option("mode", "permissive")
    .format("cloudFiles")
    .option("cloudFiles.format", "parquet")
    .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation","/checkpoint_directory2/")
    .option("cloudFiles.inferColumnTypes","true")
    .load("dbfs:/FileStore/tables/user_reviews.parquet")
    )
```

It gave same error what you got.

[image]

Because path what your giving is file path, instead of that you should give directory path contains `parquet` files.

**Ex:**  `dbfs:/FileStore/tables/` in your case it is
`dbfs:/mnt/raw/Entity1/`

Output:
[image]